# How to find MLE of variance

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

How do I find the Maximum Likelihood Estimation for the variance of the uniform population distribution? Where X is a simple random sample between 0 and θ.

\begin{align}
Given:V(X) = \frac{θ^2}{12}
\end{align}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that MLE actually gets complicated with regards to the uniform distribution because the parameter affects the actual domain of the random variable.  Sorry I don't remember how to get around this but I just wanted to validate that this may not be completley trivial.

Answer (score 2):

If you have observations $X_1, \dots, X_n,$ the MLE for $\theta$ in $UNIF(0, \theta)$ is the maximum observation. Because you have only one observation $X,$ it is the MLE (see below). And the MLE itself is dreadfully biased; $E(X) = \theta/2.$ But an unbiased estimate of $\theta$ based on the MLE is $\tilde \theta = 2X.$

The MLE of the variance is $X^2/12.$ (Invariance principle for MLEs.)
And, once you have your unbiased estimate $\tilde \theta$ of $\theta,$ you might try using $\tilde \theta^2/12$ to estimate the variance. However, both $\hat\theta^2/12$
and $\tilde \theta^2/12$ are biased estimates of the variance. (It isn't part of your problem, but maybe you can find an unbiased estimate of the variance based on the MLE $X$ of $\theta$.)

Let's look at a simulation in R of a million performances of the one-observation
experiment. Suppose $\theta = 10.$  On average, how well can we estimate 
$\theta?$  And how about the variance, $\theta^2/12?$
Although one can't expect much from any one experiment with only one observation,
because there is high variability, the average behavior of the unbiased estimate based on the MLE is not bad. Neither the MLE $\hat \theta^2/12$ of the variance
nor its alternative estimate $\tilde \theta^2/12$ is unbiased. [$E(\tilde \theta^2/12)$ ia illustrated.]

I don't know how
familiar you are with simulations or with R, so this may be a waste of your time,
but take a look and see if the comments (at `#`s) make any sense.

```
 m = 10^6;  th = 10;  x = runif(m, 0, th)
 MLE = mean(x); UNB = 2*MLE;  MLE; UNB
 ## 5.000518  # Aprx E(X) = E(MLE),  close to theta/2
 ## 10.00104  # Aprx E(unbiased est), close to theta
 mean((2*x)^2/12);  th^2/12
 ## 11.10941   # Aprx E(alt est of var). Too big, biased.
 ## 8.333333   # Exact value of var
```

---

**Finally,** why do I say the $X$ is the MLE of $\theta$?. Because the pdf
(or likelihood function) of $UNIF(0, \theta)$ is discontinuous, you
can't use differentiation to find the MLE.  Suppose you observe $X = 5.3.$
Then here is a plot of the likelihood function. It is clear that the
maximum is at 5.3.

```
th = seq(0, 15, by=.001);  LIKE = dunif(5.3, 0, th)
plot(th, LIKE, type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, so if I have the MLE for $\theta$ then I can just plug into the equation for the variance to get its respective MLE? $\hat\sigma^2$ = $\hat\theta^2/12$ ?

Comment: by the Invariance Principle

Comment: Right. But not all MLEs are unbiased. And _unbiasedness_ does not 'survive' nonlinear transformations.